# MacOS is showing a badge notification on System Preferences. How can I make it disappear?

Tags: upgrade, notifications

The badge notification is because it wants me to upgrade to Catalina. I never want to upgrade to Catalina because my hardware is too old to be run under any newer version of MacOS than I already have.

How can I dismiss this particular notification or otherwise make the notification badge go away?

I tried System Preferences --> Notifications, to see if I could disable all badge notifications from the System Preferences app, but that doesn't appear to be an option. And really, I don't want to disable *all* notifications from System Preferences, I just want to tell it to to stop nagging me about the Catalina upgrade.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344278/how-can-i-disable-the-red-software-update-notification-bubble-on-the-system-pref, because here it is being asked how to remove the **Catalina** upgrade notification. The other question wants to remove **all** available update notifications. It would be overkill to remove all notifications here.

Comment: @n1000 I doubt what else would bring in notifications. Updates for Mojave will also be discontinued soon. If OP wants, better sign up for a website that sends mails for Mojave updates and kill all notifications.

Comment: @n1000 the solution I gave on that question has continued to work for Catalina and Big Sur, so even if the question specified Mojave it is still the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same complaint. I removed System Preferences from the Dock, and and haven't been bothered by the badge nag.

System Preferences is still easily available in the Apple Menu > System Preferences.

And you might review [this Stack Exchange question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344278/how-can-i-disable-the-red-software-update-notification-bubble-on-the-system-pref?rq=1) for an alternative solution.