# Stop System Preferences Software Update to notify me of a OS update

Tags: mojave, software-update, notifications, system-settings

I am on Mojave and I will not ever upgrade to Catalina because I have 32 bit stuff I am not planning to ditch.  Software Updates in System Preferences still shows that there is one 'update', i.e. a major OS upgrade (see pic).  This is annoying and I'd like not to have this notification.  How can I turn it off?[image: My doc showing the notification]

Comment: Silly me, the answer is here: [disable the red Software Update notification bubble](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344278/how-can-i-disable-the-red-software-update-notification-bubble-on-the-system-pref)

Comment: AFAIK that only disables the notification badge but your system is still checking for Catalina updates. You can use this instead to stop it from checking for the update altogether: `sudo softwareupdate --ignore "macOS Catalina"`

Comment: Actually, I tried both, and while it does not tell me there is a Catalina update, the red notifications reappears by itself after sleep.