# Red dot showing in the software update icon but already updated

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, software-update

I just updated my Macbook to the latest version of Mac OS: Catalina 10.15.4.

However, I noticed that in the system preferences, there is a red dot on the software update icon, but after clicking it, it says it is already up to date...

So I want to know why it is here and how can I get rid of the red dot?

Thanks in advance!
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

> **Fortunately, after upgrading to 10.15.5, the red dot disappears...**

Answer (score 2):

```
defaults delete com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs; killall Dock
```

This can get rid of it but it will return.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, I also updated from Mojave to Catalina 10.15.4 directly because I have heard about many bugs in the previous version from my friends...

Comment: See also this popular answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344279/53510

Answer (score 1):

Try running `softwareupdate -ia` in terminal to force it to realise it's got them all / install any you may have missed.

Comment: Same here, updated straight from latest 10.14.x to 10.15.4, `-ia` doesn't make a difference. `softwareupdate --list` shows nothing to update. `softwareupdate --dump-state` log doesn't seem to contain any pending updates either

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your comment, but it seems does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Permanent solution (close "settings" window first):

Via Terminal:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.plist
defaults delete com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs
defaults delete com.apple.systempreferences DidShowPrefBundleIDs
killall Dock
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't take the credit but saw the solution from Macrumors forum:

Simply delete the following file
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.plist

Exactly same situation. This solves my problem after me upgrading to Catalina.

Reference:
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/software-updates-badge-wont-disappear-after-the-update-to-catalina-10-15-4.2228115/post-28312219