# macOS Big Sur System Preferences Notifications Customize

Tags: macos, notifications, big-sur

I am running os 11.2.3 and wanted to customize notifications from system preferences. Specifically, software update notifications show up when there is a new version to upgrade to. However, they always show up as alert notifications. I would like them to display as banners, so it will disappear even if I do not dismiss it. Looking at `System Preferences --> Notifications`, there is no option for 'System Preferences' unlike other apps (Safari, Messages, etc.).

**How can I change the settings/format for the system preference notifications?**

Comment: Is your goal basically just to avoid dealing with these notifications in the first place? If you disable checking for updates automatically and then [follow the instructions in this related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344279/134123), you may be able to avoid the notifications entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there isn't an option to customize the system alerts notifications display so you can't do that .